# Programmatic Application of CSS Stylings in iText7 (not html2pdf)

Tags: css, itext, styles, themes, itext7

I'm working on upgrading from iText5 to iText7. I'd like to take advantage of the ability to use CSS to define and apply styles - but I'm not doing html2pdf conversions. We are presently programmatically building up our reports. Is there a nice way whereby we can set CSS for the Document and have the styles applied as the Document is constructed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building the element structure based on the elements in `layout` module since you are not using pdfHTML. There is no 1-1 correspondence between CSS styles and the styles you can set to elements from `layout` module - some CSS styles affect the resultant structure of the elements and the contents of the elements (e.g. changes in capitalization etc), and pdfHTML add-on takes care of all that.

This means there is only a very limited possibility to apply your existing CSS styles to the element structure from `layout` module. The best approach is to write HTML+CSS markup and use `HtmlConverter#convertToElements` to convert to `layout` element structure. You will have to write some code to serve as bridge between CSS and layout. Example:

```
Document document = new Document(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("C:/out.pdf")));

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello world");

Map<String, String> cssStyles = new HashMap<>();
// Font size is the required field
cssStyles.put("font-size", "12pt");
cssStyles.put("color", "red");
// No shorthand properties are allowed
cssStyles.put("border-left-color", "black");
cssStyles.put("border-left-style", "solid");
cssStyles.put("border-left-width", "1px");

DummyStylesContainer container = new DummyStylesContainer();
container.setStyles(cssStyles);

ProcessorContext context = new ProcessorContext(new ConverterProperties());
context.getCssContext().setRootFontSize(12);

BlockCssApplier applier = new BlockCssApplier();
applier.apply(context, container, new DummyTagWorker(p));

document.add(p);

document.close();
```

The helper class definitions:

```
private static class DummyStylesContainer implements IStylesContainer {
    private Map<String, String> map;

    @Override
    public void setStyles(Map<String, String> stringStringMap) {
        this.map = stringStringMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getStyles() {
        return map;
    }
}

private static class DummyTagWorker implements ITagWorker {
    private IPropertyContainer container;

    public DummyTagWorker(IPropertyContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void processEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processContent(String content, ProcessorContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processTagChild(ITagWorker childTagWorker, ProcessorContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        return container;
    }
}
```

Result: [image: result]